# Filter octave vector by bool array

Tags: octave

I have a vector in octave that looks like this:

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,99]
```

an a bool vector that looks like this:

```
% [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,99]
B=[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1]
```

and I would like to use B to filter A like this:

```
filter(A,B)=>[1,6,8,99]
```

soo that for each element in A where the equivalent elment in B is 0, it gets removed from A
Whats an efficient way to do this?

Comment: A `,` missing in your solution? Do you want `[1,6,8,99]`? I guess you are looking for logical indexing: `A(B==1)`

Comment: perfect, thank you. The 99 is there to avoid people giving solutions that only work for perfect ranges

Comment: Nevermind you are right. Fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try `logical` for indexing, e.g.,

```
A(logical(B))
```

which gives

```
>> A(logical(B))
ans =

    1    6    8   99
```